# Prove that $A \mapsto A (A + \lambda)^{-1}$ is Frechet differentiable for any positive matrix $A$ and for any $\lambda \gt 0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative, matrix-analysis

> Show that the map $f : A \mapsto A(A + \lambda)^{-1}$ is Frechet differentiable for any positive matrix $A$ and for any $\lambda \gt 0.$ Also find it's Frechet derivative.

Is the space of all positive matrices open subset of the space of all self-adjoint operators? If it is the case then we could have written $f(A + B) - f(A)$ as follows $:$ $$f(A + B) - f(A) = B (A + \lambda)^{-1}- (A + B)  (A + B + \lambda)^{-1} B (A + \lambda)^{-1}.$$ From here I would guess that $$Df(A) (B) = B (A + \lambda)^{-1} - A (A + \lambda)^{-1}B (A + \lambda)^{-1}.$$ But for that we need to show that if $\|B\|$ is sufficiently small then $$\|(A + B)  (A + B + \lambda)^{-1} B (A + \lambda)^{-1} - A (A + \lambda)^{-1}B (A + \lambda)^{-1}\| = o (\|B\|)$$ which I am unable  to do. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: I have a couple of notation questions: 1. When you add a scalar $\lambda$ to a matrix, am I correct in assuming that you are adding the scaling matrix $\lambda I$, where $I$ is the appropriately-sized identity? 2. The matrix $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm for the Euclidean norm on the appropriately-sized Euclidean space, right?

Comment: @Theo Bendit$:$ For $(1)$ you are right. It is usually denoted in this fashion in the context of spectral theory. For $(2)$ we could have taken any norm we like since in a finite dimensional normed linear space any two norms are equivalent. If you wish you can freely work with Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the function
$$f(A)=A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}=I-\lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}.$$
To form the Frechet derivative,
\begin{align}
   &f(A+B)-f(A)= \\
  &=\lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}-\lambda(B+A+\lambda I)^{-1} \\
  &=\lambda (A+\lambda I)^{-1}-\lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}(B(A+\lambda I)^{-1}+I)^{-1} \\
  &=\lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}-\lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(B(A+\lambda I)^{-1})^n(-1)^n \\
  &\approx \lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}(B(A+\lambda I)^{-1}+\cdots)
\end{align}
So the Frechet derivative is the linear term in $B$ on the right, which is
$$
   f'(A)B= \lambda(A+\lambda I)^{-1}B(A+\lambda I)^{-1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$, $y$ be arbitrary with $x$ invertible. Suppose that
$$z = (x^{-1} - y)^{-1}$$
exists. Then

$$z = x + xyx + xyzyx\text{.}$$

If the norm satisfies $\|uvu\|\leq \|u\|^2\|v\|$ for all $u$, $v$, then

$$(1 - \|x\|^2\|y\|^2)\|z\| \leq \|x\|(1+ \|x\|\|y\|)\text{.}$$
If furthermore $\|y\| < \|x\|^{-1}$, then

$$\|z\| \leq \frac{\|x\|}{1-\|x\|\|y\|}$$
so that

$$\|z-x-xyx\| \leq \frac{\|x\|^3\|y\|^2}{1-\|x\|\|y\|}\text{.}$$

Finally, set $x = (A + \lambda)^{-1}$, $y = -B$. Then

$$\|f(A+B)-f(A)-\lambda (A+\lambda)^{-1}B(A+\lambda)^{-1}\| \leq \frac{\lambda\|(A+\lambda)^{-1}\|^3\|B\|^2}{1-\|(A+\lambda)^{-1}\|\|B\|}\text{.}$$